# Adding data to end of existing file python

Tags: python, file-io

So my code looks like this ....
but I want to add data always to the end of the document 
how would I do this

```
try:
    f = open("file.txt", "w")
    try:
        f.write('blah') # Write a string to a file
        f.writelines(lines) # Write a sequence of strings to a file
    finally:
        f.close()
except IOError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the file using `'a'` (append) instead of `'w'` (write, truncate)

Besides that, you can do the following isntead of the `try..finally` block:

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('blah')
    f.writelines(lines)
```

The `with` block automatically takes care about closing the file at the end of the block.

Answer (score 4):

open the file with "a" instead of "w"

Comment: **Re**open? If he opens it with `w` before, it'll already be empty.